# how to get some business parameters in rejectedExecution?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

Java multi thread execute tasks, and explicitly construct `ThreadPoolExecutor` like below

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1), myRejectedExecutionHandler);
```

and submit tasks by below way

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int articleId = i;
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> articleId, threadPool);

}
```

now I want to custom `rejectedExecutionHandler`

```
void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor);
```

but how can I get articleId? because I want to log the rejected articleId in `rejectedExecution` e.g.

```
log.warn("article: {} is rejected, please process it manually", articleId);
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: not use custom rejectedExecutionHandler and catch the RejectedExecutionException

```
catchRejectedException(()->CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> articleId, threadPool), articleId);

private void catchRejectedException(Runnable task, int articleId) {
    try {
        task.run();
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        log.error("article: {} is rejected", articleId, e);
    }
}
```